# Botium Webhook connection error to Kore.ai

Tags: webhooks, botium-box

I want to integrate Botium Community Edition with our Kore.ai platform. I've created a Webhook channel and set the generated Webhook Url, Client ID and Client Secret in my testbot on Botium. When I select Live Chat and hit Connect I get a 'ChatBot Connected' message. However, when I try to chat with my bot I get the following error:

```
    Failed sending to chatbot: rest request failed: { Error: tunneling socket could not be 
    established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 at ClientRequest.onError  
    (/app/server/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:177:17) at Object.onceWrapper 
    (events.js:285:13) at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:197:13) at Socket.socketErrorListener 
    (_http_client.js:397:9) at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13) at emitErrorNT 
    (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8) at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3) at 
    processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Please advice! Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your KOREAI_WEBHOOK_URL capability is pointing to localhost (127.0.0.1) - this won't work

Comment: Thanks Florian! Actually, I used the webhook url generated on my Kore.ai platform. https://kore-631-c21.xxxxxxx.xxx/chatbot/hooks/st-064467c6-5c99-5b24-bca1-xxxxxxx - which is of course on a different server. Btw. Botium Sample Chatbot is working properly. I assume this either a firewall issue or I missed a configuration step which enables the communication between Botium and external servers.

Comment: is there an HTTPS proxy configured maybe ?

Comment: this really looks like a proxy issue